Android Connect AWS IOT core
Currently, I'm starting to learn how to develop an Android app that can connect to the AWS IOT core using Certificates and can then do pub/sub messaging using the MQTT method.
The problem here is:
Is it possible that after creating and downloading the Certificate to use in the app, if there are many applications that install this app, will anything unreasonable arise? Is there a need to do something to secure Certificate files when importing into Android Source code?
I searched for some sample code but couldn't find any discussion on this issue.
